# Outlook VSTO Add-In: Can not resolve recipientname

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in

I'm programming an outlook add-in.
I want to modify the mail before it gets sent. Therefore I have registered me for an event before the email gets sent. I can modify it but when I m trying to change the recipient of the mail (so mail.To) it gives me an error (not while my code is running but when outlook tries to sent the mail).

Error says: '...Can not resolve the receivername' (i have translated it so it is not the real error text but close to it)

Here is my code:

```
void Application_ItemSend(object item, ref bool cancel)
    {
        if (item is Outlook.MailItem mail)
        {
            var to = mail.To;
            var body = mail.Body;
            var editedBody = to + "#" + body;
            mail.Body = editedBody;
            mail.To = @"<another email>";
        }
    }


private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Register the new event
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting all To recipients. Is that what you really want to do? Try to use `MailItem.Recipients.Add` (retuns `Recipient` object) followed by `Recipient.Resolve`.

You are also setting the plain text `Body` property wiping out all formatting. Consider using `HTMLBody` instead, just keep in mind that two HTML strings must be merged rather than concatenated to produce valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the action by setting the `cancel` parameter to true and schedule re-sending operation with a new email address. A timer which fires the `Tick` event on the main thread can help with that task.

Also you may consider making a copy of the email, changing recipients (do any changes on the copy) and submit it. In that case you will have to differentiate such messages and skip them in the `ItemSend` event handler. To get that working you may use `UserProperties`.

Comment: You don't need to cancel the message submission if all you want to do is add or modify message recipients.

Comment: I am not sure that it can work at this stage. Sometimes, you have to cancel any further processing and re-submit the item anew. So, it depends on the requirements.

Comment: Modifying the message in ItemSend always worked for me. The only time I had to abort the submission was when I either (a) took over the submission completely, (b) had to perform some lengthy operation and I did not want to block the main Outlook thread or (c) I had to delete the message or close the inspector.

Comment: Yeah, either I do.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working:

```
                    var to = string.Empty;

                    mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();

                    foreach (Outlook.Recipient r in mail.Recipients)
                    {
                        to += r.Address + ";";
                    }
                    if (to.Length > 0)
                        to = to.Substring(0, to.Length - 1);

                    mail.Body = to + "#" + mail.Body;

                    //Modify receiver
                    mail.To = string.Empty;
                    Outlook.Recipient recipient = mail.Recipients.Add("<email>");
                    recipient.Resolve();
```